# Ruby Rails Postgis - Finding all the points in a polygon

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis

I would like some help on constructing sql queries for use in rails with activerecord-postgis-adapter. I have been doing quite a bit of reading but am now a bit stuck, any help would be much appreciated.

I have the two models Events and Areas:

Events have a 'geometry' column which is of type Point

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.rgeo_factory_generator = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator    
end

t.spatial  "geometry", :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"polygon", :geographic=>true}
```

Areas have a 'geometry' column which is of type Polygon

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.rgeo_factory_generator = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator
end

t.spatial  "geometry", :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}
```

I can create and plot both events and areas on a google map, and create areas by clicking on a map and saving to the database.

I want to be able to do the follow 2 queries:

1. @area.events - show all the events in an area
2. @event.areas - show all the areas a single event is in

I know i might be asking a bit much here, but any help would be much appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Just to clarify...are you looking for a SQL script to do this or ruby answer?  The Postgres SQL script for this is relatively straight forward (use ST_contains) and I can give you a full script if you provide the schema for these two tables and how they relate.

Comment: Hi Twelfth... I would like to implement it in rails, and am not sure quite how to do it, i guess i would like a join table between Areas and Events AreasEvents for example, as i want to be able to view events that are in a given area, and given an event see all the areas that it is within, but i cannot see how i would implement this with standard rails associations. I need the solution to be fast as there will be a large number of Events, so i think i need to use ST_contains. I have not yet implemented any relationships between the tables. Dose this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will be a bit of a work in progress for you.  I'm weak with ruby on rails, but I should be able to help you through the DB section.

You have two tables, Area which holds a polygon and Event which holds the event as a single point (it's a bit more complicated if the event is also an area and you're trying to pick out overlapping area's...if events are single points this works).

```
Select *
from area a inner join event e on 1=1
```

This is going to create a list of every area joined to every event...if you have 500 events and 20 area's, this will query will return 10'000 lines.  Now you want to filter this so only events that are within the area they've been joined to.  We can use st_contains for this as st_contains(polygon,point):

```
where st_contains(a.polygon,e.point) = 't'
```

If you run this, it should give you a.*,e.* for all events within area's.   Now it's just a matter of counting what you want to count.

```
select a.id, count(1)
from area a inner join event e on 1=1
where st_contains(a.polygon,e.point) = 't'
group by 1
```

This will give you a list of all your area's (by id) and the count of the events in it.  Switching out a.id with e.id will give a list of event id's and the number area's they are in.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to express these queries within Ruby, but the DB concepts that you'll need are here...

For speed considerations, you should look into the GIStree indexing that Postgres has...indexed polygons perform exponentially better.

Edit:

PostGIS is a contrib file that comes with Postgres but does not exist in a standard install...you'll need to find this contrib file.  These will install a series of GIS functions within your database including ST_Contains. (functions reside in a database, so make sure you install the functions in the DB you are using)

The second thing the PostGIS contrib files installs is the template_postGIS database which is required for the geometry datatypes (geom as a data type won't exist until this is installed).

Comment: You could always wrap that sort of SQL in `Area.find_by_sql('select a.* from area a ...')` to get objects out of ActiveRecord. BTW, sorry to ruin the cool 666 rep but someone had to do it.

Comment: heh thanks...I'll just have to go random down vote 10 items to get it back ;)

Comment: thanks this is great... 2 questions, 1, i get the following error https://gist.github.com/1685908 i think that all my data is in the SRID so is it because my database dose not have the postgis functions? 2. you mentioned GIStree i did a quick search and did not find anything, can you give me a link. Many thanks again this is a real help.

Comment: Ah, sorry...assumed you had installed the contrib files.  Postgres has a series of 'contrib' files that are functional add-ons to the Postgres database (usually done as a bunch of functions)...DBlink provides the ability to call a different database, but does not come in the standard install.   PostGIS is also a contrib file...read the edit on the answer, I'll put that info there

Comment: Answer for question number 2: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/gist.html   I think it's technically a btree_gist index...same concept as r-tree within Oracle I believe.

Comment: thanks twefth, it turns out that i did have the postgis functions added, it was that i was mixing geometry and geography arguments. All working now! Now just to sort out the active_record bit and get and get rid of the find_by_sql. Again many thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick way to do this. These will simply return arrays of ActiveRecord objects.

```
class Area
  def events
    Event.joins("INNER JOIN areas ON areas.id=#{id} AND st_contains(areas.geometry, events.geometry)").all
  end
end

class Event
  def areas
    Area.joins("INNER JOIN events ON events.id=#{id} AND st_contains(areas.geometry, events.geometry)").all
  end
end
```

You probably should memoize (cache the result) so that you don't query the database every time you call the method. That should be straightforward; I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

It *may* be possible to get sophisticated and wrap this up in a true Rails association proxy (so you can get all the Rails association goodies). I haven't looked into this though. It wouldn't be a standard Rails association in any case, because you're not storing IDs.

Twelfth is right: you should create spatial indexes for both tables. Activerecord-postgis-adapter should make those easy to do in your migration.

```
change_table :events do |t|
  t.index :geometry, :spatial => true
end

change_table :areas do |t|
  t.index :geometry, :spatial => true
end
```

If you're having trouble with installing postgis, I recently wrote up a bunch of blog entries on this stuff. Check out http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/category/tech/georails. I'm also the author of rgeo and activerecord-postgis-adapter themselves, so I'm happy to help if you're stuck on stuff.

Comment: thanks Daniel, this is really good, yes i got postgis installed correctly the errors i was getting where due to thinking that my columns should be geographical... your gems are fantastic by the way, many thanks for all the work you have put into them.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is the best answer I've found. Did you get around to looking at getting this to work with association proxies? Great blog series btw and thanks for all the rgeo goodness :)